# Akka and Apache Camel advantages over Apache Service Mix and others ESB

Tags: java, scala, integration, akka, esb

In terms of high performance, scalability and massive concurrency for systems integration  through xml data exchange, would worthwhile develop a solution with few channels and simple using Akka and Camel instead to adopt an mamut ESB solution?

I Know that apache service mix uses camel behind scenes for engine message mediation between services. But and about of performance that akka can provide

Comment: So what is the question? The question, as stated, is very vague and doesn't really have an answer beyond "it depends"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides not seeing a real question, I can tell you that there are several non-mamut ESB solutions available, especially in the open source environment.

It depends on what you wanna do. If you need for example monitoring and administration for your "channels", why not use a lightweight ESB (ServiceMix, Fuse, Talend, WSO2, Fiorano, ...) instead of implementing it by yourself?

Maybe you should tell us a little bit more about your problem - to discuss if a "real" ESB or Camel + Akka is the better choice...